# Assign a value to a variable with IL MethodBuilder

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm building a dynamic type that inherits from the original type, and I'd like to store the original type in it's interface:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    Type OriginalType { get; }
}
```

So I can use the original when I need instead of dynamically created type.

```
FieldBuilder _original = typeBuilder.DefineField("_original", typeof(Type), FieldAttributes.Private);

PropertyInfo originalProperty = typeof(IProxy).GetProperty("OriginalType");

// - Building the getProperty, omitted for brevity
// - Then, during the constructors construction:
foreach (ConstructorInfo constructorInfo in typeBuilder.BaseType.GetConstructors())
{
    // - Parameters, omitted
    ConstructorBuilder constructorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, CallingConventions.Standard, parameters);
    ILGenerator ilGen = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    // - I want to assign a variable to the local '_original' with a value I have present at this moment
    // - This doesn't work!
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeBuilder.BaseType);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, _original);

    // - Calling the original constructor   
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= parameters.Length; i++)
    { ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, i); }
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, constructorInfo);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
```

How can I assign a value like this? Is there a specific OpCode for that, or is there a way for a class to "know" it's base class during construction?

Comment: My recommendation would be to first do the equivalent of what you want to emit in C# and then look at the MSIL disassembly for that.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I don't know how, that's why I asked if there's a way to assign it by a specific value during creating (as if I've typed the base type, which I don't know at compile time is). If I type the result using a specific type, that specific type shows up in the ILCode from ILDasm which is not really what I need...

Comment: Do you really want to store the `System.Type` object for the type being inherited, or do you actually want to store an _instance_ of that type?  That is, if you were defining `class MyDynamicClass : MyBaseClass`, would the `_original` field be defined as `Type _original` or as `MyBaseClass _original`?  Storing the `System.Type` seems less useful, which is why I ask.

Comment: @Andrew I need the Type, that's because instead caching the dynamic class if it's of a type I've already proxied, but my proxy generator simply takes any object and proxy it... I need the original type so I can check if it's already a proxy, I use the existing one instead of creating a proxy of a proxy...

Comment: @Teter28's answer appears correct for the problem you are describing: specifically, you needed to load `this` onto the stack. However, given your reasoning, why not just have the proxy generator check whether the object implements your proxy interface?  You could accomplish something similar with an attribute as well.  If you still need to know the original type, you might make your proxy interface generic, like `IProxy<YourOriginalClass>`.

Answer (score 1):

_original is a field of your generated type.

If you want to set value for this field you have to to : this._original = myvalue; it is equivalent to... ldarg_0 + [EmittedValue] + stfld(_original). in you case [EmittedValue] is a type : ldtoken(type) + call(Type.GetTypeFromHandle)

```
ldarg_0 //this
ldtoken //typehandle
call Type.GetTypeFromHandle //TypeHandle to Type
stfld _original //setfield (must be follow ldarg_0 and value as Type)
```

Comment: _original is a field of your generated type. If you want to set value for this field you have to to : this._original = myvalue; it is equivalent to... ldarg_0 + [EmittedValue] + stfld(_original). in you case [EmittedValue] is a type : ldtoken(type) + call(Type.GetTypeFromHandle)